# How to draw circle with specific color in XNA?

Tags: colors, drawing, xna, geometry

XNA doesn't have any methods which support circle drawing.
Normally when I had to draw circle, always with the same color, I just made image with that circle and then I could display it as a sprite.
But now the color of the circle is specified during runtime, any ideas how to deal with that?

Comment: I remember reading something like that on XNA's forums.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can simply make an image of a circle with a `Transparent` background and the coloured part of the circle as `White`. Then, when it comes to drawing the circles in the `Draw()` method, select the tint as what you want it to be:

```
Texture2D circle = CreateCircle(100);

// Change Color.Red to the colour you want
spriteBatch.Draw(circle, new Vector2(30, 30), Color.Red);
```

---

Just for fun, here is the CreateCircle method:

```
    public Texture2D CreateCircle(int radius)
    {
        int outerRadius = radius*2 + 2; // So circle doesn't go out of bounds
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, outerRadius, outerRadius);

        Color[] data = new Color[outerRadius * outerRadius];

        // Colour the entire texture transparent first.
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            data[i] = Color.TransparentWhite;

        // Work out the minimum step necessary using trigonometry + sine approximation.
        double angleStep = 1f/radius;

        for (double angle = 0; angle < Math.PI*2; angle += angleStep)
        {
            // Use the parametric definition of a circle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Cartesian_coordinates
            int x = (int)Math.Round(radius + radius * Math.Cos(angle));
            int y = (int)Math.Round(radius + radius * Math.Sin(angle));

            data[y * outerRadius + x + 1] = Color.White;
        }

        texture.SetData(data);
        return texture;
    }
```

Comment: I know this thread is really old, but your code returns a circle for me. Would you by any change know how i can fix this?

Comment: @Weszzz7, Isn't it SUPPOSED to return a circle?